# Cannot output correct child process time in C interactive shell

Tags: c, shell, clock

I am working on a interactive C shell and outputting user CPU time and system CPU time of child process after executing fork.  I use `.tms_cutime` and `.tms_cstime` but the output is negative.  If I check using `clock()`, both outputs become 0s, no matter what code is run.

I got user time is -0.010000s and system time is -1400864714735.760010s.

Update: I tried to put `times(&child_time_start);`  before `fork()` or `wait(NULL)`.  Both give me 0.00000s which is wrong.  May I ask how to solve?

Below is the code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <sys/times.h>



int main(void) {
    struct tms child_time_start, child_time_end;
    int clock_tick;
    clk_tk = sysconf(_SC_CLK_TCK);
    
    while (1){
        pid_t pid = fork();

        //child process
        if (pid == 0){
            times(&child_time_start);    //start time count in child process
        
            execlp("/bin/ls", "ls", (char *) 0);
            printf("not successful");
            exit(1);
        }

        //parent process
        else{
            wait(NULL);
        
            times(&child_time_end);   //end time counting
            printf("child user time is %f s  child system time is %f s\n", (double) (child_time_end.tms_cutime - child_time_start.tms_cutime) / clk_tk, (double) (child_time_end.tms_cstime - child_time_start.tms_cstime) / clk_tk);
        }
        
    }
    return (0);
}
```

Comment: Why `(char*) 0` and not `NULL`?

Comment: That looks a lot like an uninitialized value.

Comment: Hint: You're initializing `child_time_start` in the child process and expecting it to magically transport over to the parent process. This will absolutely not happen. Your variable is filled with junk, hence the junk output. Why don't you initialize prior to the `fork()`?

Comment: Rather than the rather bland, uninformative `printf("not successful");`, you should write an error message that explains what went wrong, and you should write it to the proper stream.  eg `perror("/bin/ls");`

Answer (score 0):

The child process is a copy of the parent process, but does not share its variables with it - instead, it starts with a copy of the parents variables. For that reason, the line

```
times(&child_time_start);    //start time count in child process
```

must be executed by the parent process before or after the fork. If you place it between `fork` and `if (pid==0) {`, both processes will execute it, which could be useful in some cases, and it removes the time required to do the fork from the time measurement. If you place it before the fork, only the parent process will execute it but the child process gets a copy, so both have exactly the same value here.

Comment: Thanks for your reply! I tried to put ```times(&child_time_start);    //start time count in child process``` before ```fork``` or inside child or parent process (under ```if (pid==0)``` and ```else```), they all output 0.000000s for user time and system time.  May I ask how to solve it?

Comment: I suggest you check all the fields of `child_time_start` and `child_time_end` directly, instead of calculating the time spent. Also, you might want to replace `/bin/ls` with another command that takes more time.